# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type when accessing members of a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I have the following sample code :

person.h

```
typedef struct person Person;
Person* makePerson(char* n, int i);
```

person.c

```
#include "person.h"
struct person {
    char* name;
    int age;
};

Person* makePerson(char* n, int i) {
    Person person;
    person.name = n;
    person.age = i;
    return &person;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "person.h"
int main() {
    Person* pp = makePerson("Mark",24);
    printf("Person's name : %s\t Person's age : %d\n",pp->name, pp->age);
}
```

I am getting an error of "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" when I attempt to print out the name and age members that correspond to the Person pointer, pp.

I am using gcc-std=c99 -o main main.c person.c to compile

Can anyone give me some guidance? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are trying to access `name` and `age` in `main.c`, but it doesn't know anything about them because the definition is in `person.c`.  You should move the struct definition to the header file.

Comment: Never ever returns the local variable pointer to its caller: return &person;

Comment: FYI you should use malloc inside the makePerson and return the pointer. If you just declare local variable like that, it will be gone at the end of the makePerson function call, which make your pointer pointing to a memory which is not safe to used

Comment: if you define a struct tag and a type name, consider using the exact same name for both. THat makes it simpler for everyone, and migh even make your code valid C++ too.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will rewrite makePerson to use malloc. Also is it possible to have a "fully accessible" definition in a .c file or does everything have to be in a .h file?

Comment: Look up "pImpl idiom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

printf("Person's name : %s\t Person's age : %d\n",pp->name, pp->age);

dereferences the `person` struct. However, your `.h` file includes merely a forward declaration.

Either put the print function into `person.c`, or move the full `struct` definition into `person.h`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was resolved in the comments, but you are the first on to actually put an answer